# Check if a FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs got thandled by a try and catch

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

In my project I use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` event to log any error that occurs in my program. Some exception I already handle with try and catch, but the events also triggers in a try and catch so I want to log if the Exception that got thrown already got handled.

But I got no idea how to really do that by an easy and clean way.

The Code I got now would print such for every error thrown:

`ErrorMessage: Some kind of error - Handeld: INEEDTHIS`

The `INEEDTHIS` should tell if the Exception was thrown in a try and catch or not.

Comment: You can't tell at that point: as the docs say, it _"Occurs when an exception is thrown in managed code, **before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain**."_

Comment: Do you maybe have any idea how I could implement that regardless of that?

Comment: No, sorry. Doesn't the `FirstChanceException` handler pick up exceptions thrown in (and handled by) the .Net framework?

Comment: Where would you see the difference between those two?